# Adding DnxWorkspace into my project, Roslyn

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn, workspace, dnx

I am looking into the .NET MVC projects, and is trying really hard to implement DNX workspace so I can attempt to use DNX workspace instead of MSBuildWorkspace.

I have met the error that

> Could not install package 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces.Dnx 2.4.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

There's no documentation on this error. I tried on all possible versions of .NETframework. I tried downloading and manually adding it as well. (same error)

It seems that this is the only way of changing the analyzer to be able to read MVC projects.

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

For handling Projects with a Project Json you can also use the Package `Microsoft.DotNet.ProjectModel.Workspaces` which includes the `ProjectJsonWorkspace` class. You can use it almost the same as MSBuildWorkspace:

```
var project = new ProjectJsonWorkspace(projectPath);
var projects = project.CurrentSolution.Projects;
```

I hope this has helped you.